# DB2 connection through pyodbc and pandas.io.sql in Unix Box with non-root

Tags: python, python-2.7, db2, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to IBM DB2 through python using pyodbc and pandas.io.sql, now the twist is I am not Super User or better to say I dont have any right to install DB2 Driver or anything else.

Is it possible to use pyodbc and pandas.io.sql to connect to DB2 with such conditions.

The code which I used so far is

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={FreeTDS}; Hostname=eee;Port=25369;Protocol=TCPIP;Database=rt;CurrentSchema=abc;UID=abc;PWD=efg;')
```

Error

```
pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Or is it possible to check if there is preinstalled DB2 driver.

Answer (score 1):

At a minimum you need the IBM Data Server Driver for ODBC and CLI. You don't need to be root to install it, it's just a bunch of libraries. Find the correct version here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24033997

Comment: Thanks @mustaccio... I am not sure about how to install it without root access.. can you please elaborate more on that...

Comment: I'd start here: [http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.cli.doc/doc/t0023864.html](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.cli.doc/doc/t0023864.html)

Comment: I did downloaded the DB2 driver and not sure how to connect it with python script ... any lead.....\